# how to map fields name between Java object and JSON file using GSON library

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm parsing JSON object to Java object but some fields are null.

results

```
//Printed object after parsing, some fields are null 
{host_ip='null', open=false, host_fqdn='null', nmap_results='null', cvss_vector='cvss2#av:n/ac:l/au:n/c:c/i:c/a:c', cvss=10.0, attackvector='n', list_
of_ports=null, ports___port='null', plugin_family='Windows', scanner_name='Local Scanner', operating_system='null', plugin_name='Microsoft Windows XP Unsupported
Installation Detection'
```

Usage of Gson library:

```
 for (int v = 0; v < splunk_results_as_Array.size(); v++)
                    {
                        String vuln_as_string = splunk_results_as_Array.get(v).toString();
                        Splunk_data splunkdata = new Gson().fromJson(vuln_as_string, Splunk_data.class); // parsing happens here
                                   System.out.print("\n Splunk : Splunk Java Object created \n" + splunkdata.toString());
                        splunkdata.ports_to_List();
                        splunkdata.setDataType(dataType);
                        list_of_Hosts.add(splunkdata);
                    }
```

Json object as string

```
"result":
{"cvss_vector":"cvss2#av:n/ac:l/au:n/c:c/i:c/a:c","host-ip":"XX.XX.XX.XX","plugin_family":"Windows","scanner_name":"Local Scanner","plugin_name":"Microsoft RDP RCE (CVE-2019-0708) (uncredentialed check)","hostname":"XX.XX.XX.XX","cvss":"10.0","attackvector":"n","ports{}.port":"3389"}
}
```

as you can see the fields : host-ip and ports{}.ports do have value.

The classed used:

```
public class Splunk_data
{
    private String host_ip;
    private boolean open;
    private String host_fqdn;
    private String nmap_results;
    private String cvss_vector;
    private double cvss;
    private String attackvector;    
    private String ports_port;
    private String plugin_family;
    private String scanner_name;
    private String operating_system;
    private String plugin_name;
     }
```

I think what caused the problem is host_ip doesnot match host-ip but I Java not possible to use '-' so I used '_'.

is there a way how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use different name for the variable than the actual key in JSON, you can use `@Serialized` annotation.

```
@Serialized("host-ip")
private String host_ip;
```

This will work and parse your host-ip as string.